# How to make jquery-ui's autocomplete combobox widget fill after click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is it possible to render jquerui autocomplete combobox after page loaded with "focus" event ?

Menu before user click:

```
<select>
 <option>Choose Something</option>
</select>
```

Menu after user clicked:

```
<select>
<option>Loading options</option>
</select>
```

Menu after options loaded from server:

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq8tq/9/) i have been working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use input.val("text") for changing fancy input values:

```
    .click(function() {
        alert("test");
        input.val("loading");
        alert("test");
        // close if already visible
        if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
            input.autocomplete( "close" );
            return;
        }
```

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nH3b6/35/).